# RapidMiner: Replace Value with a value from another column/attribute

Tags: replace, missing-data, rapidminer

My Problem is that if I have a missing value in a row, I want to replace this value with another one from that row. For example I want to replace the missing value with the appropriate "Belegnummer" [image: picture of a row with a missing value]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you have made some attempts, please show us the code that you used. What exactly is a "missing value" ? Is it the string "?" ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general there is a operator called *Replace Missing Values* which does exactly what the name suggests.

In your special case you want to access the values of another attribute (column), so  the *Generate Attributes* operator offers a very powerful expression builder where you can declare an If-statement of that form `if(a1==MISSING_NUMERIC, a2,a1)`

[image: Replace missing values with the *Generate Attributes* operator]

See the screenshot above for an example or copy&paste the process XML into your RapidMiner process window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.000-BETA">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" name="Process">
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Subprocess" width="90" x="112" y="34">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="a1"/>
        <parameter key="mode" value="expression"/>
        <parameter key="expression_value" value="a1 &lt;5"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="380" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="a2|a1"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Declare Missing Value" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="out 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="447" y="34">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="a1_new" value="if(a1==MISSING_NUMERIC, a2,a1)"/>
    </list>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Subprocess" from_port="out 1" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
  <description align="center" color="yellow" colored="false" height="181" resized="true" width="529" x="275" y="126">With the expression parser more complex statements can be defined. In this case:&lt;br&gt;if(a1==MISSING_NUMERIC, a2,a1)&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;meaning that if the value of attribute a1 is missing, it will be replaced by the value of a2 otherwise the value of a1 is kept.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Instead of creating a new attribute the old one can also be overwritten&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br&gt;</description>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```